# Native windows c++ programming?

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, native, environment

I have quick question about native c++, along with others, programming on windows-- I recently wrote a small c++ program in Visual Studio on my own computer that does a little math for me. I compiled it successfully and moved the .exe from the VS debug folder to my desktop. It runs fine on my computer, regardless of where the .exe is located. But then I gave the program to my friend, and when he tries to run it, it says he's missing all kinds of dll files. Now I have a feeling this is because there is a c++ environment that is included in VS, that allows it to run on mine and not his. But my question is why should it matter what language the program was originally written in? Isn't the point of compiling it into a .exe to turn the code into machine language so that it can run on any computer regardless of whether or not that have the dev tools?

Comment: Use static linking or install the redistributable pack. The redistributable pack is less convenient but it can be updated without you having to recompile your program if there are fixes for it.

Comment: static linking at compile time? and the redist pack on every system I want to run my program on?

Comment: No, just do one _or_ the other. Either statically link to the C runtime (which I assume is missing) or have your friend install the appropriate VC++ redistributable pack. You can use Dependency Walker (on your friends' machine) to see exactly what DLL-s are missing but if your program is small and you haven't added any explicit 3rd-party DLL dependency, it'll likely just be the C runtime.

Comment: Static linking will give you bigger exe files but pretty much everything will be compiled into the executable (except 3rd-party stuff).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling a debugging version will dynamically link to debug version(s) of dll files that don't come standard with Windows. You're also not technically/legally allowed to redistribute debug versions of dll files. Either compile a release version, or include whatever .dll files you are linking to with your exe file. You might also have to worry about whether or not the target computer has the proper Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Redistributable Packages installed.

Alternately, you can statically link by setting Runtime Library->Multithreaded /MT under Code Generation in your project's properties, thereby bypassing dll hell, although for various reasons I won't go into, this is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

In *theory*, the Exe file can run on any computer with suitable CPU etc.
(same opcode "language" as yours).

Practically, there are two major problems:

a) The program file contains more than CPU commands, what and how depends on eg, your operating system. Exe (PE) files are usually used in Windows, and while it is theoretically possible, Linux won´t run it because nobody programmed it in a way to understand Exe files (there is additional software like Wine, which *can* run Exe´s on Linux, but that has to be installed separately)

b) You´re not writing every bit from the OS from scratch, you´re relying that you can use a lot of pre-existing functions. As you know, these have to be present to run your program. The problem is, Visual Studio assumes the presence of libraries which are intentionally not part of Windows itself. It wouldn´t be a problem to ship them with every Windows installation, but Microsoft choose to keep them as separate download (the Redist. package mentioned in the comments). To stuff as much as possible in the Exe file without relying on other library files, use the static linking option for your project.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is unrelated to language. If you are missing dependencies/libraries, with anything, of course it is going to yell. It's expecting to use code from the other dll to know how to do something.

A good example is when you run a .exe and it says HEY! We noticed you're missing this driver/file/dependency and then it takes you to some other click through's to get it.

Comment: so I'm correct in expecting the .exe to be able to run on any system? Edit: the missing dll is MSVCP120D.dll

Comment: That's the C debug runtime.

Comment: No, you're incorrect. Even though any machine can run it can't guarantee that his machine has the same libraries as you.

Comment: so it's an assumed dependencies issue, not an environment issue?

Comment: It is a dependency issue.